# Bootstrap datepicker - Parse date

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I'm using the pretty good [eternicode's/bootstrap-datepicker](https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker) jQuery plugin.

I'm trying to use the included [DPGlobal](https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker/blob/master/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js#L947) tools to do some date operations.

Example:

```js
dpg = $.fn.datepicker.DPGlobal;
date_format = 'dd/mm/yyyy';
date_str = '31/12/2013';
console.log(dpg.parseDate(start, date_format));
```

returns me (on firefox)

> TypeError: format.parts is undefined

What am I doing wrong ?

---

Check out [my fiddleable](http://jsfiddle.net/LcrJR/) example

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You also have to parse the format before you use `parseDate(...)` :) .

```
dpg.parseDate(date_str, dpg.parseFormat(date_format))
```

I've updated your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LcrJR/1/).

Comment: Thank you very much, you win (4s before @Arun :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to parse the `format` first using `parseFormat(format)`

```
$('body').append($('<div />').text(dpg.parseDate(date_str, dpg.parseFormat(date_format))));
```

Demo: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Q4Yllhw8cBZdnYb3iFu2?p=preview)